# Difference between Java API and Java framework

Tags: java

In general API is a set of prewritten packages and interface and classes and Framework is set of classes which provides ready-made architecture for developing applications.is there any main difference between the above two?

Answer (score 0):

In general when you make a class to work with an API, your class invokes the API classes.

Instead, when you make a class to work with a framework, your class is invoked by the framework classes.

This is called Inversion of Control (IoC).

Also, an API normally does nothing by itself. A framework, could work by itself, providing some default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

An API is an end point to which your application connects to delegate some procedure.

A framework is a separate system which exposes an API so that you can delegate tasks to it.

In short: `<Your Application>    <->  [<API> <-> <Functionality> Framework]`.

Thus, you can say that a framework provides you with an API to delegate tasks to it and an API abstracts the functionality a framework provides.

Answer (score 0):

An API is (obviously) an *interface*. An API could also have multiple implementations, which, at least in theory, can be swapped (see for example [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API)).

A framework, on the other hand, is a collection of classes which provide basic infrastructure and interfaces for integration with your application. A framework could also implement an API (see for example [hibernate](http://hibernate.org/)).